# How i can make (appendTo) to this code HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I want make `appendTo` use jQuery in blogger to this HTML
and this code to make profit sharing system so that each writer in the blog has its own advertising units and also has a description and rank in the blog.

```html
<b:includable id='AUTH'>
  <b:tag name='script' type='text/javascript'>(function(){
  var snapAuthor=AuthorsInfo.filter(function(a){
    return a.name===&#39;<data:title/>&#39;
  })[0];
  if(snapAuthor!==undefined){
    snapAuthor.provided=true;
    <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
      <b:switch var='data:link.name'>
        <b:case value='top-ad' />snapAuthor.topAd=&#39;<data:link.target.jsEscaped/>&#39;;
        <b:case value='mid-ad' />snapAuthor.midAd=&#39;<data:link.target.jsEscaped/>&#39;;
        <b:case value='bot-ad' />snapAuthor.botAd=&#39;<data:link.target.jsEscaped/>&#39;;
        <b:case value='rank' />snapAuthor.rank=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
        <b:case value='about' />snapAuthor.about=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
        <b:default/>snapAuthor.links[&#39;<data:link.name/>&#39;]=&#39;<data:link.target/>&#39;;
      </b:switch>
    </b:loop>
  }
  })(); 
  </b:tag>
</b:includable>
```

When I `appendTo` the elements:

```
snapAuthor.about.appendTo(".author-about")
snapAuthor.rank.appendTo(".author-rank")
```

...to this HTML:

```
<div class='author-about'/>
<div class='author-rank'/>
```

...it produces the following error:

> snapAuthor is not defined

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: consider formatting your code better, the first js part is close to unreadable, linebreaks plz.

Comment: sorry .. i don't understand u !

Comment: We don't understand you either

Comment: I took a stab at formatting your code, but I've never done anything with blogger code, so please do [edit] your question if you find it not to your liking. As far as your code goes, those `appendTo` would appear to need to be placed within the `if(snapAuthor!==undefined){` block...